# What happens when we introduce a third 'paradox' possibility to the Halting Machine?

Tags: turing-machines, formal-systems

Thanks to Turing, we know that it is impossible to construct a machine that can prove for all machines whether they halt or not. This then has mayor implications on many other fields and theorems, since they can be restated using the halting problem.

However, what if we were to construct a machine that is able to realize that it is being 'fooled'? 
So rather than machine $H$ which returns `halts` if machine $M$ halts and `diverges` if $M$ does not, $H'$ returns `halts` if $M$ trivially halts (when $H$ returns `halts`), `diverges` if it trivially does not (when $H$ returns `diverges`), and `paradox` if the outcome depends on the outcome itself (when $H$ would be stuck in a paradox when being fed a program $M$ whose outcome depends on $H(M)$).

- Would it be possible to 'side-step' the halting problem in this way? Or is there a way to show that even this extended machine $H'$ will struggle for certain machines $M$?
- Would machines like $H'$ (and the formal system $F'$ that side-steps Gödel's incompleteness theorem in the same way) be useful in practice, or be crippled in some way?

Comment: The problem is that the machine has no idea if it is going to halt or not.  That's what the Halting Problem asks...given a program, and a specified input, will the program halt or not?

Comment: Would you consider a machine that always answers `paradox` to be correct? If not, please provide a rigorous definition of the inputs for which this answer is allowed.

Comment: In particular, "depends on itself" is a very fluffy definition. Not that in the usual argument against the halting problem being decidable, the fact that the answer "depends on itself" is not an innate property of certain inputs to the halting problem, but a conclusion we reach from the _assumption_ that the machine we're looking at correctly decides the halting problem. This assumption turns out to be _counterfactual_ in all cases, so the argument does not actually identify any concrete input to the halting problem that would "depend on itself".

Comment: @HenningMakholm I have clarified the question somewhat.

Comment: "Stuck in a paradox" is not something that happens _to the machine_ in the first place. The contradiction arises only in _our reasoning, external to the machine_ about how _we_ would expect it to answer.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Correct, but why does that matter for the definition of $H'$? $H'$ is a machine that works similar to $H$ but does not depend on $H$ being constructable itself. Maybe "$H'$ returns `paradox` whenever a contradiction would arise in reasoning about $H$ on $M$" is clearer?

Comment: @Qqwy: You're still trying to define some _machine's_ behavior by referencing whether a contraction is being thought about in _our_ brains ... Try to write up exactly what it is you propose _with all the details being explicit_ (including what it means for a machine to be "stuck in a paradox", which is a concept that otherwise doesn't figure in the definition of what Turing machines do at all), instead of just hinting at it in comments.